# Error while trying to run jar in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, jar

I am getting following error while trying to run  jar through hadoop command prompt

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: /tmp/NewJar.jar    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:124)
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:136)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:122)
```

Answer (score 3):

Most probable causes :

**- Incorrect path of the jar.**

**- Improper permissions on the folder where Hadoop is trying to run the jar file.**

Please make sure you have specified the correct path and you have proper directory permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused by **permission issue for me.**

My jar file has the permission **rw-r--r--** by default. I changed it to **rwx-rwx-rwx** through command `chmod 777 my_jar.jar`. And the error went away.